# How to delete all other keys but keep 1 key in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, key

I have a dictionary like this:

```
family = {'mother':'Alice', 'father': 'Richard', 'son': 'Toni'}
```

How can I delete other keys but keep 'son' key?

Sorry for misunderstanding, I just mean how to delete all other keys but keep 1 key in the dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just:

```
son_value = family['son']
family.clear()
family['son'] = son_value
```

or iterate over your keys:

```
for k in family:
    if k != 'son':
        del family[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the *last* key because [dictionaries are not ordered](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

If you simply need the sub-dictionary with item `'son'`, you can use:

```
>>> family = {'mother':'Alice', 'father': 'Richard', 'son': 'Toni'}
>>> subdictionary = {'son': family['son']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
family = {'mother':'Alice', 'father': 'Richard', 'son': 'Toni'}
family = {'son': family['son']}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually *clear* the original `family` dict.  If there are other references hanging around, it might not be what OP wants.  (then again, it might be perfectly fine ... It's really a matter of whether OP is asking for what he/she **actually wants** or **thinks he/she wants**)

Comment: @mgilson True but hopefully OP writes good code that won't have that problem!